# How to abort scenario if there is no data in DB

Tags: karate

I'm checking if data exist in DB, if not skip the scenario and move on to the next one
This is what I'm doing, but it's aborting the build even if there is data returned

```
* def dbData = db.readRow("SELECT top 1 * FROM table where data = 'x'")
* if (dbData != '#notnull') karate.abort()
```

This aborts the build even if data is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this use case, assuming `dbData` is a `List` or JSON array, this would work:

```
* if (!dbData.length) karate.abort()
```

BTW, `!dbData.length` is a short cut for `dbData.length !== 0`